# Clarification about Select from (select...) statement

Tags: sql, select

I came across a SQL practice question. The revealed answer is

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(a - c) + ABS(b - d), 4) FROM (
SELECT MIN(lat_n) AS a, MIN(long_w) AS b, MAX(lat_n) AS c, MAX(long_w) AS d 
FROM station);
```

Normally, I would enocunter

```
select[] from[] where [] (select...)
```

which to imply that the selected variable from the inner loop at the where clause will determine what is to be queried in the outer loop. As mentioned at the beginning, this time the select is after 
**FROM** to me I'm curious the functionality of this. Is it creating an imaginary table?

Comment: Yes, that creates a temporary table - but is that already the full question?

Comment: @NicoHaase - not in most SQL database systems it doesn't. Most such systems have a concept of temporary tables (either the ANSI standard definition or their own), and this isn't it.

Comment: The full question was about calculating distance between 2 coordinates on 2D Plane. I could not remember which theorem it was using the maximum and minimum values of longitude as Point1 and maximum and minimum values of latitude as Point2 in the station table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever okay, I was just thinking in terms of MySQL - but can you explain what else that query shows if you state that it is not a temporary table?

Comment: @NicoHaase - it's called a [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html), not a [temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's true and obvious, but the OP asked whether the **execution** of that query containing a subquery created some kind of imaginary / temporary / whatever you call it table.

Comment: @NicoHaase - yes, but using the *wrong* terminology for things (when that terminology already has a clear, different meaning in that area) is a *barrier* to learning.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever once again, seconded. But then please help me too by sharing the proper explanation: what does the execution of a query containing a subquery do, in terms of evaluating the subquery? I think that might get a highly upvoted answer

Answer (score 3):

The piece in parentheses:

```
(SELECT MIN(lat_n) AS a, MIN(long_w) AS b, MAX(lat_n) AS c, MAX(long_w) AS d FROM station)
```

is a subquery.

What's important here is that **the result of a subquery looks like a regular table to the outer query**.  In some SQL flavors, an alias is necessary immediately following the closing parenthesis (i.e. a name by which to refer to the table-like result).

Whether this is technically a "temporary table" is a bit of a detail as its result isn't stored outside the scope of the query; and there is an also a thing called a temporary table which *is* stored.

Additionally (and this might be the source of confusion), subqueries *can also* be used in the `WHERE` clause with an operator (e.g. `IN`) like this:

```
SELECT student_name
  FROM students
 WHERE student_school IN (SEELCT school_name FROM schools WHERE location='Springfield')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is, as discussed in the comments and the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52288686/15498) a subquery.

Logically, such a subquery (when it appears in the `FROM` clause) is executed "first", and then the results treated as a table<sup>1</sup>. Importantly though, that is *not* required by the SQL language<sup>2</sup>. The entire query (including any subqueries) is *optimized* as a whole.

This can include the optimizer doing things like pushing a predicate from the outer `WHERE` clause (which, admittedly, your query doesn't have one) down *into* the subquery, if it's better to evaluate that predicate earlier rather than later.

Similarly, if you had two subqueries in your query that both access the same base table, that does *not* necessarily mean that the database system will *actually* query that base table exactly twice.

In any case, whether the database system chooses to *materialize* the results (store them somewhere) is also decided during the optimization phase. So without knowing your exact RDBMS and the decisions that the optimizer takes to optimize this particular query, it's impossible to say whether it *will* result in something actually being stored.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that there is no standard terminology for this "result set as a table" produced by a subquery. Some people have mentioned "temporary tables" but since that is a term with a *specific* meaning in SQL, I shall not be using it here. I generally use the term "result set" to describe any set of data consisting of both columns and rows. This can be used both as a description of the result of the overall query and to describe smaller sections within a query.

<sup>2</sup>Provided that the final results are the same "as if" the query had been executed in its logical processing order, implementations are free to perform processing in any ordering they choose to.

Answer (score 0):

As there are so many terms involved, I just thought I'll throw in another answer ...

In a relational database we deal with tables. A query reads from tables and its result again is a table (albeit not a stored one).

So in the `FROM` clause we can access query results just like any stored table:

```
select * from (select * from t) x;
```

This makes the inner query a subquery to our main query. We could also call this an ad-hoc view, because view is the word we use for queries we access data from. We can move it to the begin of our main query in order to enhance readability and possibly use it multiple times in it:

```
with x as (select * from t) select * from x;
```

We can even store such queries for later access:

```
create view v as select * from t;
select * from v;
```

In the SQL standard these terms are used:

- **BASE TABLE** is a stored table we create with `CREATE TABLE ...`. `t` in above examples is supposed to be a base table.
- **VIEWED TABLE** is a view we create with `CREATE VIEW ...`. `v` above examples is a viewed table.
- **DERIVED TABLE** is an ad-hoc view, such as `x` in the examples above.

When using subqueries in other clauses than `FROM` (e.g. in the `SELECT` clause or the `WHERE` clause), we don't use the term "derived table". This is because in these clauses we don't access tables (i.e. something like `WHERE mytable = ...` does not exist), but columns and expression results. So the term "subquery" is more general than the term "derived table". In those clauses we still use various terms for subqueries, though. There are correlated and non-correlated subqueries and scalar and non-scalar ones.

And to make things even more complicated we can use correlated subqueries in the `FROM` clause in modern DBMS that feature lateral joins (sometimes implemented as `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`). The standard calls these **LATERAL DERIVED TABLES**.